# How can I append new lines from 1 CSV to another existing CSV

Tags: python-3.x

In the code below the program reads a CSV that already exists. A second CSV file is presented and the code needs to extract and append the new lines in the output CSV. The code is working properly. However, I want to know if it is possible to write a cleaner/nicer piece of code.

How can I clean up the code better?

```
input_file = 'Cached_data//cache_2.csv'
output_file = 'Output//current-date_output.csv'

with open(output_file, 'r') as out_file:
    lines_out = []
    for line in out_file:
        lines_out.append(line)

with open(input_file, 'r') as in_file, open(output_file, 'a+') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if line in lines_out:
            continue
        else:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Content cache_2.csv:

```
"line 5"
"line 6"
"line 7"
"line 8"
```

Content of output.csv:

```
"line 1"
"line 2"
"line 3"
"line 4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
with open(output_file, "r+") as out_file, open(input_file, "r") as inp_file:
    out_content = out_file.readlines()
    out_file.writelines([line for line in inp_file.readlines() if line not in out_content])
```

Comment: It should be a+ instead of r+ as it will overwrite the output file instead of appending the contents. So it will only write contents which are not common between two files but it will delete all contents and then write it.

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav It does not overwrite the content because first it reads it

Comment: Agreed first it reads but while performing write operation it will delete the old output file and write the new output file with uncommon data between the files.

Comment: ```r+``` Open for reading and writing. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.


```a+``` Open for reading and appending (writing at end of file). The file is created if it does not exist. The initial file position for reading is at the beginning of the file, but output is appended to the end of the file (but in some Unix systems regardless of the current seek position).

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav With r+, the position is initially at the beginning, but reading it once will push it towards the end, allowing you to append. With a+, the position is initially at the end.

Comment: Ohk. Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't sure about this. So i thought it will replace the file. Thanks :-)

Comment: You're welcome! r+ does not create the file if it does not exist though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. It will work.

```
input_file = 'Cached_data//cache_2.csv'
output_file = 'Output//current-date_output.csv'
with open(input_file, 'r') as in_file, open(output_file, 'a+') as out_file:
    lines_out = []
    for line in out_file:
        lines_out.append(line)
    for line in in_file:
        if line not in lines_out:
            out_file.write(line)
```

a+ mode allows you to read as well as edit the file. So no need of first loop to read the file.

To reduce further:-

```
input_file = 'Cached_data//cache_2.csv'
output_file = 'Output//current-date_output.csv'
with open(input_file, 'r') as in_file, open(output_file, 'a+') as out_file:
    lines_out = []
    [lines_out.append(line) for line in out_file]
    [out_file.write(line) for line in in_file if line not in lines_out]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open('./file1.csv', 'a').writelines(open('./file2.csv', 'r'))
```

This [appends](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) file2.csv to the end of file1.csv.. It'll create file1.csv if not found first time too.